# C++ CGI script, reading form data

Tags: c++, c, forms, cgi

I've been using [this tutorial](http://library.thinkquest.org/16728/content/cgi/cplusplus.html) to make C++ CGI script. However, it's not compiling when I try to read the form POST data:

```
  char* lpszContentLength = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
  char* lpszBuffer;
  int nContentLength = atoi(lpszContentLength);

  lpszBuffer = malloc(lpszContentLength+1);  // allocate a buffer
  memset(lpszBuffer, 0, lpszContentLength+1);  // zero it out

  fread(lpszBuffer,1,lpszContentLength,stdin);  // get data
```

Here's the compiler's complaint:

```
cgi.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cgi.cpp:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘size_t’
cgi.cpp:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void* malloc(size_t)’
cgi.cpp:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’
cgi.cpp:13: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
cgi.cpp:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘size_t’
cgi.cpp:15: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’
```

Where ln 12 is the one starting with "lpszBuffer".

I'm new to C++ so I'm unsure how to fix this, or why this might be happening. Maybe it's just outdated code... I would happily accept some other solution to read the data from a POST request.

**Edit:**
I've updated the code according to your guys' fixes.

```
  char* lpszContentLength = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
  char* lpszBuffer;
  int nContentLength = atoi(lpszContentLength);

  lpszBuffer = (char*)malloc(nContentLength+1);  // allocate a buffer
  memset(lpszBuffer, 0, nContentLength+1);  // zero it out

  fread(lpszBuffer,1,nContentLength,stdin);  // get data
```

However, I still get a Segmentation fault from atoi:

```
==23419== Invalid read of size 1
==23419==    at 0x498DA8C: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:298)
==23419==    by 0x498D7EF: strtol (strtol.c:110)
==23419==    by 0x498AB60: atoi (atoi.c:28)
==23419==    by 0x8048899: main (in .../cgi.cpp.cgi)
==23419==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

What's the problem here? I'm assuming it has something to do with POST form submission if the POST is blank...

Comment: Should not `malloc(lpszContentLength+1)` be `malloc(nContentLength+1)`? Also in `memset()` and `fread()` too...

Comment: This code has got nothing to do with C++. The tutorial is horrible. I suggest first finding a good C++ book and *then* dabbling in CGI.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed... I'll try other things instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type-cast issue with `C++`. `lpszBuffer` is a `char*`, however, `malloc` returns a `void*`. So you need to cast it to `char*`. Also note that you are trying to use a `char*` (lpszContentLength) as an integer value which is not true. This must be updated in your other functions as well - you have converted it earlier using the `atoi` function; so use that value.

So the line should read

```
lpszBuffer = (char*)malloc(nContentLength+1);
```

Finally, to use `memset`, you must `#include <string.h>` in the beginning of the source file.

Also, as good practice (especially if the script runs for any significant amount of time), do not forget to `free` your memory when you are done with it. That is, anything allocated with `malloc` should have `free` called on it when you are no longer going to use it. So if you use `lpszBuffer` through the entire function, at the end of the function simply do `free(lpszBuffer);`

Comment: "`lpszBuffer` is a `char*`, however, `malloc` returns a `void*`. So you need to cast it to `char*`." This is actually not true - In C, the cast is not required, and generally not recommended

Comment: However, if you look at the tutorial, the code is definitely C++. So, the cast will be required, and it's incorrect to say it's not C++.

Comment: I agree (I did not look at the tutorial) that this is `C++` code. The snippet of code he posted have more details which suggest `C`. However, where do you find that such a cast in `C` is not recommended? Casting the result from `malloc()` is perfectly safe since it's your own "vanilla" chunk of memory. But more importantly, such a cast stops the compiler from warning (which it shouldn't) and improves readability of the code.

Comment: @RageD Thanks a lot. I've updated the code, still getting an error with atoi though. See update above.

Comment: You know what, never mind. this tutorial is horrible. Thanks for your help

Comment: @varatis: No problem. Your issue with `atoi` seems to be that `lpszContentLength` is NULL

Answer (score 0):

> error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘size_t’

This is caused by trying to use `lpszContentLength` (which is a `char*`, in this case a string of characters presumably representing a number), as a `size_t` (usually a long integer). To solve this, you will first need to convert `lpszContentLength` to an integer value. I'd recommend [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) for this, since it will detect errors - which you will need to handle.

Looking at the tutorial, they've already converted it using `atoi()`. You could also fix this error by using `nContentLength` everywhere they've tried to use `lpszContentLength` by mistake. Their code must have never been tested.

Note that `atoi()` doesn't detect errors - so once you're done with the tutorial, it would be a good learning exercise to change to `strtol()` with appropriate error checking.

---

> error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’

This is caused by missing the cast to `(char*)` on the return value of malloc. In C++, the cast is required:

```
lpszBuffer = (char*)malloc(convertedNumber+1);
```

---

> error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope

This is caused by not including the header for memset. The [man page for memset](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memset/) tells you you'll need to add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

---

> error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘size_t’
>
> error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’

These are both caused by lpszContentLength being a string of chars, when it needs to be an integer type. See the first error above.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I've updated the code, however I still get a problem. See update above.

Comment: BTW I think it's something having to do with the POST data being blank (since the script is submitting the form to itself). But even if I check sizeof(lpszContentLength) > 1 before doing the atoi, atoi still seems to trigger and fail.

Comment: You know what, never mind. this tutorial is horrible. Thanks for your help